# Python: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror

I am making a program where the computer asks the user to enter a number and keeps asking until a blank line is entered. Every time a value is entered it checks if it is a number. If it is, then, it will append it to a list. Once a blank line is entered, it will print all the numbers and prime numbers.

The problem I am having is that I can't make the number an 'int' and a 'string' at the same time. Every time I make the number an 'int' it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append' and every time I make it a 'str' it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I make the code work?

Here is the code (what I have done so far... Not finished yet):

```
even_no = []
print('Prime Calculator')
# Ask for user to input number
number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
while number:

    number = str(number)
    #number = int(number)
    if number > 1:
        number.append(even_no)

        number.append(even_no)

    else:
        print('Please enter number bigger than 1')
number = (input('Enter a number: '))
```

Comment: Why are you doing `number = str(number)`?

Comment: as @tobias_k says that is an issue with this error.
You are converting an int to a string and comparing a string with an int afterwards.
Also you are trying to append a list to a number, not a number to a list in your code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append something to a list, you write `l.append(something)` and not the converse. So

```
number.append(even_no)
```

Should be replaced by

```
even_no.append(number)
```